# Do BIOSes have programmable codes? I want to introduce some modifications to my BIOS

Tags: bios

I used CPUID to extract my BIOS (CPUID -> Tools -> Save BIOS). However, I didn't see any codes that can be modified. There is only an assembly language. I expected to see something familiar, but I didn't.

The changes I want to introduce are different BIOS colors (currently, the BIOS is mostly blue) and changes to the menu order, texts, and descriptions. Is this possible?

Comment: there are people who have tried. Google for "change bios gui". On the fly, I found for example [this thread](https://winraid.level1techs.com/t/is-it-possible-to-change-a-bios-gui/30912). In any case you'll need heavy programming skills and a VERY DEEP knowledge of computer hardware. This is definitely not something for beginners.

Comment: Assembly language is a programming language. Not an easy one, but it is a programming language. If you really want to give modifications a shot, see if you can load a custom bios rom in a VM and experiment there. As long as the change is minimal, if it works in a VM, flashing that to your actual bios should in theory work. But if in practice it fails, consider that you may have to buy a new motherboard.

Comment: Even if the BIOS was written in C the compiled code is still going to be machine code ("assembler") instructions that the processor understands and not uncompiled code. The same is true for every compiled executable on your computer. What "more familiar" language we're you expecting to see?

Answer (score 4):

BIOS is machine language, viewable as assembler.

Technically, it is possible to modify a BIOS. People have absolutely done it.  However, a mistake can break your computer and it is even possible to permanently damage it.

You can Google your BIOS to see if someone has modified it, but its rare and its usually done to change (enable or disable) something specific, not to change colors or menu orders.

Additionally, changing your BIOS would void any warranty.

My personal opinion (and Im sure 99.99% of everyone else):  If everything works and you just dont like the way it *looks*, its not worth the risk of ***destroying*** your computer for something purely aesthetic.